# How to find the fastest algorithm inside a single script file?

Tags: python, algorithm, time, big-o, compile-time

I have many answers to a problem and I want to test which algorithm/answer is the best. Calculating big O notation complexity is very hard (have to do it by hand, with pen, and paper) so I decide to calculate compile time instead (which I can use coding). The problem is somehow even for the same code, the compile time keeps changing so I can't decide which algorithm is the most optimized (fastest). Below is my simple code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
st = time.time()
#st = time.process_time()
#st = datetime.now()
for i in range(6000):
    print(i)
et = time.time()
#et = time.process_time()
#et = datetime.now()
#print(et-st)
print(format(et-st,".7f"))
```

The results are different every time I run. I tried `datetime`, `process_time`, and also `cProfile` but they encounter the same problem. So my question is, is there any simple and fast way to compare different algorithms? I don't want to use big O notation since it's not efficient (very hard and takes a long time to calculate).

Below is my actual code, the problem is to Find the pair of numbers in a list whose product is the largest. For example in a list [5,1,2,4,3] then the pair of numbers is 5, 3 which has the largest product (5*3=15). I have 3 solutions, 1 using nested loop, 1 using itertool.combination, 1 using sorted. Somehow all I get is 0.000... second for different input (I tested all 3 methods and get the right result for all 3).

```
import time
import cProfile
import itertools
n=int(input())
list0=[]
for i in range(n):
    ele = int(input())
    list0.append(ele)

def pairwise1(list0): #Using nested loop for each value in a list
    result = 0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(x+1,n,1):
            if list0[x]*list0[y] >= result:
                result = list0[x]*list0[y]
    return result

def pairwise2(list0): #using itertools
    list1 =  list(itertools.combinations(list0,2)) # for example list1 = [(1, 6), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), (6, 2), (6, 4), (6, 3), (2, 4), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
    sum0 = 0
    for i in list1:
        if sum(i)>=sum0:
            sum0=sum(i)
            result = i[0]*i[1]
    return result

def pairwise3(list0): #using sorted
    list0.sort(reverse=True)
    result = list0[0]*list0[1]
    return result

# cProfile.run('pairwise1(list0)') #0.0000 second, didn't work
# cProfile.run('pairwise2(list0)') #0.0000 second, didn't work
# cProfile.run('pairwise3(list0)') #0.0000 second, didn't work

st1 = time.time()
pairwise1(list0)
et1 = time.time()
print(format(et1-st1,".20f")) #still 0.0000... second

st2 = time.time()
pairwise2(list0)
et2 = time.time()
print(format(et2-st2,".20f")) #still 0.0000... second

st3 = time.time()
pairwise3(list0)
et3 = time.time()
print(format(et3-st3,".20f")) #still 0.0000... second
```

Ok, I figure it out. The input is too small, after changing my code a bit, inputting a large list (10000 elements randomly) all become clear, sorting method is always the fastest, taking only 0.001 seconds, then come to the nested loop method, finally, the iter method takes the longest. I repeat the test many times and the result won't change much.

Comment: Perhaps [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) will help.

Comment: The `time.time()` function is affected by a lot of things, the current computer running processes and more, this is a very bad method to estimate the complexity...

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think timeit is for a small code only, my actual code is quite long, the code above is only my simple example.

Comment: @Eilonlif Yes, I know. Do you have any other ideas for this problem?

Comment: Send here the entire code or try to calculate its complexity the hard way.

Comment: Given a slow function: Try `timeit`, but with `number=1`. To average several runs, for a more accurate result, use `repeat` option. See discussion of garbage-collection: you might also want `'gc.enable()'`.

Comment: _"Calculate **compile** time"_? You mean _EXECUTION_ time, right? Because the time it takes to be compiled has nothing to do with algorithm's complexity... Otherwise, complexity for `pairwise1` is `O(n²)`, `pairwise2` is `O(n²)` because of `combinations`, and `pairwise3` is `O(n.log2(n))` because of `sort`. It could be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Wisblade Thank you so much for the big O notation answer!

Comment: @Hoàng You're welcome, but if you don't understand how to find this yourself, you'll struggle a lot later... It's quite simple to get these `O()` mentally once used to them (no need for pen & paper, we search complexity, not proof / preconds / postconds / invariant), but the purpose is for you to _understand_ it - use my answers to see if you got it right, maybe. And as I said, problem CAN be solved in `O(n)`...